# What is wrong with this code for printing reverse of a sentence while maintaining the order?

Tags: java, algorithm, string, reverse

```
public String reverse(String sentence){
    String reverse = "";
    char [] s = sentence.toCharArray();
    int first = s.length-1;
    int last = s.length-1;
    String temp = "";

    for(int i = s.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        temp = " ";
        while(s[first] != ' '){
            System.out.println(s[first]);
            first--;

        }
        while(last != first){
            temp = s[last] + temp;
            last--;
            i--; 
        }            
        reverse = reverse + temp;
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

My input is: `Something for test.`

Expected Output: `test. for Something`

My Actual Output: `test.`

Please let me know what is wrong with this?  I know it's a long way to do but I was trying to minimise the use of readily available functions.

Comment: Did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Your algorithm is too complicated for its own good. I would try to think of simpler approach first instead of debugging this monstrosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reverse the words in a sentence, I'll do it like this :

```
public String reverse(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    String ret = "";
    for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ret += words + " ";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you want to stick with your approach, you can use the [`lastIndexOf(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) method to find all spaces instead of looping on a `CharSequence` and then the [subString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method to extract each word.

Answer (score 2):

When you loop for the first time and decrement first, at the end of the loop s[first] points to `' '`. When you get into the the for loop the second time, the test

```
while(s[first] != ' ')
```

fails as s[first] still points to the `' '` that you stopped at the last time. Consequently you only get the very last word and nothing more.

Try decrementing first just before you end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving that output because you're decrementing i here:

```
    while(last != first){
        temp = s[last] + temp;
        last--;
        i--; 
    }
```

There are two ways to do this properly, but if you're going to do it this way, you should use whatever string library there is to cut the string up for you.  On top of that, your current algorithm would cause `first` to go past 0, into the negatives, causing some sort of error, presumably.

```
public String reverse(String sentence){
    String reverse = "";
    char [] s = sentence.toCharArray();
    int first = s.length-1;
    int last = s.length-1;
    String temp = "";

    for(int i = s.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        while(s[first] != ' ' && first!=0){
            first--;
        }
        if (first!=0) temp = s.substring(first+1, last);
          else temp = s.substring(first, last);
        last=first;
        reverse = reverse + temp + " ";
    }

    return reverse;
}
```

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use substring, and instead want to keep your original algorithm, then all it needs is the removal of the `i--;` line.

(I see someone else has posted an answer using `split(" ")`, which would probably be even better.)

Comment: @all: Thanks for the suggestions.... I was of the thought that can I write a code without using utility function from the String class... thats why followed this approach.... anyway thanks again... :)

Comment: @Ankur Yep... you can.  The only thing messing up your code was the `i--;` in the nested while loop.  Problem is that libraries are almost always faster than code that you write yourself.  They feature the best algorithms, and they're also optimized heavily.